# Ultimate Fade-in Slideshow initially fades in from black, how to change?

Tags: slideshow, fadein

I would like to change the colour/image that the [Ultimate Fade-in Slideshow](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm) fades in from once the images have loaded, currently it is black or another dark colour or an image.

See here: [link text](http://plumridgeprint.co.uk/)

Before the first image shows the box is black/dark and then the first image fades in, how do I change this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no option for setting the initial background colour.  It's pretty easy to change yourself though.  Line 54:

```
css({position:'absolute', left:0, top:0, width:'100%', height:'100%', background:'black'})
```

Change `black` to whatever you want.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I was searching for #FFFFFF in the code to no avail!